# 2D array slicing and replacing vlaues in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array, and its size is based on a variable. I would like to change the values of specific rows and columns based on an equation.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

size = 6
weight = np.ones([size, size])
weight[size / 6 * 2:size / 6 * 4 + 1, :] = 5

print(weight)
```

But I got an error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I think `size / 6 * 2` and `size / 6 * 4` are integers.

How can I fix it?

And if I have to set `size / 6` equal to `float`, for example, `7 / 6`, how can I write a code to make `7 / 6` into the closest integer to avoid the error shown above?

Comment: Replace `weight[size/6*2:size/6*4 + 1, :] =5` by `weight[int(size/6*2):int(size/6*4 + 1), :] =5`

Comment: `7/6 = 1.1666666666666667`, but `int(7/6) = 1`

Comment: It's picky.  1.0 is not an integer.

Comment: Use // instead of /. Floor divide returns an integer, true divide always returns a float just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python supports two types of division natively. Floor division is performed with `//`, and always results in an `int`. True division is performed with `/` and always results in a `float`.

You can check with the following:

```
>>> size = 6
>>> type(size / 6)
float
>>> type(size // 6)
int
>>> size / 6 == size // 6
True
```

So the simplest way is to write:

```
weight[size // 6 * 2:size // 6 * 4 + 1, :] = 5
```

Alternatively, you can make the cast explicit, although this is less efficient:

```
weight[int(size / 6) * 2:int(size / 6) * 4 + 1, :] = 5
```

By the way, if you want to do a ceiling divide, just add `(6 - 1) = 5` and do floor divide:

```
weight[(size + 5) // 6 * 2:(size + 5) // 6 * 4 + 1, :] = 5
```

If you want to round, add `6 / 2 = 3.0` and do floor divide:

```
weight[(size + 3) // 6 * 2:(size + 3) // 6 * 4 + 1, :] = 5
```

And of course you can round explicitly:

```
weight[round(size / 6 * 2):round(size / 6 * 4) + 1, :] = 5
```

All of these options will work for values of `size` that are non-integer multiples of 6.